# Syntax ViewData in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

Can anyone explain to me what the following syntax mean?

ViewData ["greeting"] = (hour <12 ? "Godd morning" : "Good afternoon");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> hour <12 ? "Godd morning" : "Good afternoon"

This [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(VS.80).aspx) call (equivalent for if then else structure) will provide the string Godd morning if the value of `hour` is less than 12 and otherwise Good afternoon.

That result is put into ViewData["greeting"] which can later on be used in your view to display the message.

Answer (score 1):

You mean the operator on the right? It's `Conditional Operator` and it's like:

```
condition ? if_true : if_false
```

So in here if the `hour` is less than 12 then `ViewData ["greeting"]` will have string `Godd morning` assinged. Otherwise `Good afternoon` will be assigned.

You can read more about this operator [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

This line passes data from the controller to the view template. The view template can use the content of ViewData["greeting"] for its processing. For example:

```
<p>
   <%: ViewData["greeting"] %>, earthling!
</p>
```

If the value of the variable hour is less than 12 the message will be "Godd morning, earthling", otherwise it will be "Good afternoon, earthling!".

Basically the boolean expression `hour < 12` will be evaluated. If it is `true` the expression between the `?` and the `:` will be assigned to `ViewData["greeting"]`. If it is false then the expression after the `:` will be assigned to the left side.

You can replace

```
ViewData ["greeting"] = (hour <12 ? "Godd morning" : "Good afternoon");
```

with this equivalent code:

```
if( hour < 12 )
   ViewData["greeting"] = "Godd morning";
else
   ViewData["greeting"] = "Good afternoon";
```

Comment: I think that he asked about syntax. Not about ViewData mechanism ;)

Comment: @Lukas: Thank you. I think it could be both, so I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is the same thing as:

```
if (hour < 12)
   ViewData ["greeting"] = "Good morning";
else
   ViewData ["greeting"] = "Good afternoon";
```

Is just a ternary operator to simplify this common structure.

As ŁukaszW.pl said, just:

```
yourCondition ? isTrue : isFalse;
```

The ViewData is just a dictionary that the controller pass to the view.

The view is supposed to display data, then, you craete the "greeting" string on the controller and pass it to the view to display that information.